# Downloading images from S3 and showing them using SwiftUI results in high memory usage

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, swiftui, combine, awss3transferutility

Hey  So I am downloading images from AWS S3 and show them in my app using a swiftUI LazyVGrid.

My code to download is the following:

```
class S3CacheFetcher: Fetcher {
    
    typealias KeyType = MediaItemCacheInfo
    typealias OutputType = NSData
    
    func get(_ key: KeyType) -> AnyPublisher<OutputType, Error> {
        return download(mediaItem: key).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private func download(mediaItem: KeyType) -> AnyPublisher<OutputType, Error>{
        let BUCKET = "someBucket"
        
        return Deferred {
            Future { promise in
                guard let key:String = S3CacheFetcher.getItemKey(mediaItem: mediaItem) else { fatalError("UserPoolID Error") }
                print("Downloading image with key: \(key)")
                AWSS3TransferUtility.default().downloadData(fromBucket: BUCKET,
                                                            key: key,
                                                            expression: nil) { (task, url, data, error) in
                    if let error = error{
                        print(error)
                        promise(.failure(error))
                    }else if let data = data{
// EDIT--------
                        let encrypt = S3CacheFetcher.encrypt(data: data)
                        let decrypt = S3CacheFetcher.decrypt(data: encrypt)
// EDIT--------
                        promise(.success(decrypt as NSData))

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
....
// EDIT---------

// In my code I have a static function that decrypts the images using CryptoKit.AES.GCM

// To test my problem I added these two functions that should stand for my decryption.

    static var symmetricKey = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)
    static func encrypt(data: Data) -> Data{
        return try! AES.GCM.seal(data, using: S3CacheFetcher.symmetricKey).combined!
    }
    
    static func decrypt(data: Data) -> Data{
        return try! AES.GCM.open(AES.GCM.SealedBox(combined: data), using: S3CacheFetcher.symmetricKey)
    }
}
```

My GridView:

```
struct AllPhotos: View {
    @StateObject var mediaManager = MediaManager()
    var body: some View {
      ScrollView{
          LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 3){
              ForEach(mediaManager.mediaItems) { item in
                  VStack{
                      ImageView(downloader: ImageLoader(mediaItem: item, size: .large, parentAlbum: nil))
                  }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

My ImageView I am using inside my GridView:

```
struct ImageView: View{
        @StateObject var downloader: ImageLoader
        
        var body: some View {
            Image(uiImage: downloader.image ?? UIImage(systemName: "photo")!)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    downloader.load()
                })
                .onDisappear {
                    downloader.cancel()
                }
        }
    }
```

And last but not least the ImageDownloader which is triggered when the image view is shown:

```
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    
    private(set) var isLoading = false
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private(set) var mediaItem:MediaItem
    private(set) var size: ThumbnailSizes
    private(set) var parentAlbum: GetAlbum?
    
    init(mediaItem: MediaItem, size: ThumbnailSizes, parentAlbum: GetAlbum?) {
        self.mediaItem = mediaItem
        self.size = size
        self.parentAlbum = parentAlbum
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancel()
        self.image = nil
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard !isLoading else { return }
        
        // I use the Carlos cache library but for the sake of debugging I just use my Fetcher like below
        cancellable = S3CacheFetcher().get(.init(parentAlbum: self.parentAlbum, size: self.size, cipher: self.mediaItem.cipher, ivNonce: self.mediaItem.ivNonce, mid: self.mediaItem.mid))
            .map{ UIImage(data: $0 as Data)}
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { [weak self] _ in self?.onStart() },
                          receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in self?.onFinish() },
                          receiveCancel: { [weak self] in self?.onFinish() })
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.image = $0 }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
        self.image = nil
    }
    
    private func onStart() {
        isLoading = true
    }
    
    private func onFinish() {
        isLoading = false
    }
}
```

So first of all before I describe my problem. Yes I know I have to cache those images for a smother experience. I did that but for the sake of debugging my memory issue I do not cache those images for now.

**Expected behavior:** Downloads images and displays them if the view is shown. Purges the images out of memory if the image view is not shown.

**Actual behavior:** Downloads the images and displays them **but it does not purge them from memory once the image view has disappeared.** If I scroll up and down for some period of time the memory usage is up in the Gb range and the app crashes.
If I use my persistent cache which grabs the images from disk **with more or less the same logic for grabbing and displaying the images** than everything works as expected and the memory usage is not higher than 50 Mb.

I am fairly new to Combine as well as SwiftUI so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing seems obviously wrong with SwiftUI or Combine... bear in mind that this code, as you scroll, repeatedly loads and cancels the image. So, if there's anything that retains the new instance of loaded image, this would add to memory usage.

Comment: Make sure to scale the image and cache it before displaying it

Comment: Well as the image view disappears I set it to nil. Wouldn't that prevent it?

I am downloading images that are 200 by 200px so they are small enough. And as I stated in the question that I am not caching the images for the sake of debugging.

Comment: Can you post a demo project so this can be recreated easily?

Comment: @Ryan Probably yes. I come back to you with a demo.

Comment: @Ryan
So i identified the problem but can't see why this is one and how to fix it.
I added some test encryption and decryption to simulate my decryption of the downloaded images.

If I add the encryption and decryption code in my S3CacheFetcher my memory usage is increasing without purging the images from memory.
If I remove the encryption and decryption everything works as expected.

Why does CryptoKit.AES.GCM is the problem here? Shouldn't it be released automatically if the promise returns or even if the decrypt functions is finished?

Comment: Sometimes older code needs auto release pools wrapped around it. Some CGGraphics APIs balloon to 500 mb in a combine pipeline without manual autorelease. Also, in a ForEach loop, an autorelease per iteration keeps memory usage at the iteration level rather than waiting until the end.

Comment: Unfortunately autoreleasepools does not do the trick. [I uploaded a demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/mufumade/StackOverflow67459039). Make sure to scroll up and down a few times to see the memory usage. I really appreciate if you would take a look. I would also be happy to accept your answer if you find the problem.